# To each object from the first list match an object from the second list according to the condition of equality of attributes values

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, bigdata, data-analysis

Imagine we have a finite number of districts with a finite number of houses in each of them. Each house has a number and the houses in each district are numbered from 1. One man and one woman live in each house.

We have the following class for representation people:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, district, house_number):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.district = district
        self.house_number = house_number
```

And we have two lists with objects of this class called `men` and `women`. To understand the structure of lists below is an example of adding an object to a list.

```
men.append(Person("Alex", 22, "District 7", 71))
```

It is considered that the lists are already filled with objects. So we have all men in the `men` list and all women in the `women` list. Since there are a finite number of districts, finite number of houses in each of them and each house has one man and one woman, the lengths of the lists are equal. The objects in both lists are randomized.

It is assumed that the amount of data is very large.

The goal of the problem is to find all men over a certain age (variable `min_age`) in the `men` list and to match each of them with a woman from the `women` list who lives in the same house with him.

All men found must be in the `men_new` list and women in the `women_new` list. The lists must be comparable so a man and a woman living in the same house must have the same index in the `men_new` and `women_new` lists.

I now have the following solution:

```
# We believe that lists "men", "women" and variable "min_age" are previously defined.

men_new = []
women_new = []

for man in men:
    if man.age > min_age:
        men_new.append(man)

for man in men_new:
    women_new.append(filter(lambda x: x.district == man.district and x.house_number == man.house_number, women))
```

This solution works great, but it is very slow with large amounts of data. Are there any ways to solve this problem faster? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform your women list into a dict mapping house number to woman:

```py
house_to_woman = {}
for w in women:
    house_to_woman[w.house_number] = w
```

Then you can make the last line of your code efficient using this mapping:

```py
for m in men_new:
    women_new.append(house_to_woman[m.house_number])
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is great! But unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem very well. I have given a simplified formulation of the problem, but in fact we may have several attributes whose values need to be compared. I changed the question a little to make it clearer

Comment: use a tuple for the dict key: `house_to_woman[(w.district, w.house_number)] = w` and `women_new.append(house_to_woman[(m.district, m.house_number)])`

Comment: Yes, it works! It's hard to believe, but your implementation made the program about 250 times faster. I'm shocked. Thanks, guys!

Comment: @AlexanderFedorov It's easy to believe: the call to `filter` is equivalent to a `for`-loop, so the loop `for man in new_men: ....filter(...women)` is equivalent to a nested-loop `for man in new_men: for woman in women: ...`. For N couples the original code will take `N**2` iterations to complete. For one million couples, the original code will take one million millions (ie one thousand billions) iterations to complete. By contrast `house_to_woman[m.house_number]` is a single lookup in a hashmap, which is pretty much only one operation, so the new code takes only N iterations total.

Comment: @Stef I'll keep that in mind, thanks!